# How to stop google indexing URLS containing a certain word?

Tags: php, .htaccess, robots.txt

Is there a way to stop google indexing any page that contain limit=all using robots.txt

```
http://domain.com?brand=2058&limit=all
```

my domain look like this

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use the following regex in your robots.txt file;

```
Disallow: /*limit=all
```

Tested using Googles web master tools this method works in their robots.txt tester https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool?hl=en&siteUrl=http://domain.com

**Note:** Replace domain.com with your own site in the example url

Comment: Is there any online testing tool for it because now i do not have any live domain

Comment: I've just update my answer with the tester - you will need a web master tools account to check this though.